# What does "chiqui" mean and where does it come from?

Tags: uso-de-palabras, coloquialismos, diminutivos

I heard many times about "chiqui" and "chiquitita", but I can not find their translation even by Google translate. Could anyone tell me what does these two words mean? And where do they come from?

Comment: Besides my answer below a small piece of advice.....never trust google translate nor use it as a reliable reference. It still has too much to learn.

Comment: Very common nickname in the Philippines, formerly a Spanish colony.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Any dictionary will tell you that **chico** means **small** and so does **chiquitito** since it is the diminutive of "chico".

The diminutive of **chico** could be formed in these three ways: *Chiquito*, *chiquitito* or *chiquillo*.

That being said, **chiqui** is not other than an abbreviation of "chiquito/a".

It is a colloquial way to call someone mainly on a familial or romantic/loving setting and it is very commonly used to refer to children or to a romantic partner usually when he/she is short.

**Chiqui** is the Spanish equivalent of **shorty**.

Comment: Wikipedia https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chiquitita indicates "chiquitita" is a a Spanish term of endearment for a woman meaning "little one" before commmenting on ABBA's song

Comment: @user13560 that is correct. And BTW ABBA made a full Spanish version of the song and that was very popular around latinamerica in the 80's (http://www.azlyrics.com/lyrics/abba/chiquititainspanish.html) (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ih4JqI44Qz8)

Comment: Just to add something curious, in Basque (language spoken in a region between Spain and France, older than Latin) "txiki" (read chiqui) means small.

Comment: @SergioTx WOW, what a spelling!!. Nice to know. Thanks.

Comment: @SergioTx: Maybe it is the same word, spelled with Basque's smaller alphabet ?

Comment: Well, I've seen that it comes from Latin. But Basque is older and a small is a really common word. That's all I can tell. And Basque alphabet is actually quite similar to Spanish (without v, c and q, but the sounds are there, spelled different while writting).

Comment: @SergioTx: if Basque alphabet lacks the letters "c" and "q", and the pronunctiation is the same, it's no wonder the spelling of the word is so different

Comment: It's not so different. It's actually the same. Txiki is the same as chiqui. Different letters, same pronunciation, same meaning.Ch in Basque is tx, tz or ts, and qu or c are written as k.

Answer (score 2):

The Spanish language translation of *Finding Nemo* (2003) translates the English expression "**squirt**" (a term of endearment often referring to a small child) as "chiqui". Perhaps this can provide further context for any passersby. Peace and God bless!